# angularjs ui-router - Redirect to dynamic state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I have a link called **Rounds**. When I click on it, I get a nav that displays a list of rounds (First Round, Second Round, ...).
Rounds are collected from a dynamic database (currently from a JSON file).

The state url after clicking on the link is : **/rounds**

I want the state to redirect to the first element state of the nav. For now its the **First Round** but it can be anything since the data is dynamic.

In the JSON file for each round I added an attribute **uri**, for example for **First Round** the uri is **firstround**. So what I want after clicking on the link **Rounds** to get redirect to **rounds/firstround** (in other scenario, it may be anything else which is always the uri attribute of the first object in the JSON file).

I used to do it statically using

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/rounds/', '/rounds/firstround');
```

But I want it dynamic using

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/rounds/', '/rounds/{SOMETHING-DYNAMIC}');
```

Here is the example on plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/S9dtPcuaXoXJjxMV28oU?p=preview